# PayPal capture Authorization: get money immediately

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

within an Angular Application I authorize an order and want to capture it later on the server (Spring Boot). The server request, I implemented like described here:
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK/blob/develop/checkout-sdk-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/AuthorizeIntentExamples/CaptureOrder.java

So far, this is working fine, I get the transactionId as a result. But to really get the money, I have to manually go to PayPal website, find the transaction and click a button to really get the money, since the transaction is not completed, yet. Does anybody know, if it is possible to avoid this manually stuff and complete the transaction (with the capture request) serverside? The docs unfortunately don't show any further examples.

Answer (score 0):

> to really get the money, I have to manually go to PayPal website, find the transaction and click a button to really get the money, since the transaction is not completed, yet.

You are not providing enough detail. Is the captured transaction in a Pending state? Why is the transaction in a Pending state? If it is a currency issue, you need to open a balance in that currency for those payments to be automatically accepted, or enable the receiving preference for them to be automatically converted to the account's primary currency balance.

Comment: I know, that this is not enough detail, but to be honest, I have not idea, what to provide. In the Balance it says, that the money is on hold. The single transactions are listed as pending. But the "Get your money" button is working. With that I can complete the transaction. Am I missing anything in configuration to do this automatically? The accounts primary currency is same like transaction currency.

Comment: Just found this one: https://www.paypal.com/de/smarthelp/article/my-payment-is-on-hold.-why-is-this-happening-faq3297
So is this a common practice for new accounts?

Comment: Payments can be held for many reasons. You haven't provided any information about whether and why it's on hold, so there is no advice we can give. Contact PayPal if you need support.